# awk: calculate averages in arrays, divide by column count, not KEY count

Tags: arrays, macos, awk

I was calculating averages for 14 columns using this one-liner. But after much confusion about the buggy results, I realised that my statement divides a column's sum by the number of the total occurrences of a particular array's key.
What I need: each column's sum to be divided by the number of non-blank fields of the individual column's array.
And the end result must be a single file containing all results, and on a single line, all 14 column results from a particular array.
Ie, not 14 separate files that then require getting joined somehow...
How do I get there?

Data snippet:

```
Stat;HPA;TGK;DIU;KEY
5426;967.1;-3.4;1.6;49_08_1975
5426;924.2;4;6.4;49_08_1975
257;;1;4.5;49_08_1975
257;;-1.7;3.6;49_08_1975
4177;;-0.9;5;49_08_1975
5426;923.9;-1.5;3.1;49_08_1976
5426;930.2;6.6;2.8;49_08_1976
```

This is my one-liner which uses $5 as key for array:
   `awk -F '\;' -v OFS=";" ' +$2 +$3 +$4 { key=$5 ; arrkey[key]++ ; HPA[key]+=$2; TGK[key]+=$3; DIU[key]+=$4;} END{for (a in arrkey) { print a,  arrkey[a], HPA[a]/arrkey[a], TGK[a]/arrkey[a], DIU[a]/arrkey[a] } } ' infile > outfile`

Desired output:

```
49_08_1975;5;945.65;-0.2;4.22
49_08_1976;2;927.05;2.55;2.95
```

But I get:

```
49_08_1975;5;378.26;-0.2;4.22
49_08_1976;2;927.05;2.55;2.95
```

The average for HPA on KEY 49_08_1975
needs to be 945.65 –
instead of the result of my awk code, 378.26,
which is dividing the column's sum of the two HPA occurrences by the 5 occurrences of KEY.

Comment: please reduce this to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); for example, limit to 5 columns (eg, stat, year, date, HPA, KEY), the associated (reduced) one-liner code, and do not introduce spaces ('for readability'); also verify the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output; once you have a workable solution for the reduced data set you should then be able to expand it to encompass the rest of your data

Comment: your code defines `key` as the contents of the `KEY` column but the only way I'm getting `945.65` is if the `key` is actually a combination of the `KEY` and `Stat` columns, eg, `49_08_1975` + `5426` (2 rows) => `(967.1 + 924.2)/2` => `945.65`; please update the question to confirm which input columns make up the `key`; also of help would be a confirmation on the rest of the expected values for `HPA` (I'm guessing 4x separate HPA outputs related to the 2x `KEY` values and 4x `Stat` values)

Comment: @markp-fuso The array key is $5. The particular key string in my example 49_08_1975 occurs 3200 times by many different "Stat" in the big file, and 5 times from 2 Stat in the example snippet. What you describe is the problem I am facing: if HPA or any other field is blank, this blank field should not up the division counter for calculating the average of, for example, HPA[key]/arrkey[_here_I_need_the_solution].

Comment: ok, I misread the 'non-blank' reference; so while 5x rows have `49_08_1975`, only 2x of those rows have a non-empty value in the `HPA` column; so you want to display the `5` but divide by `2` ... correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. The counter for a  column-array should only go up if the related field is not blank.  I also expanded on my earlier comment because I hit the enter key too soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- while `arrkey[a]` maintains a count of the number of times the `key==$5` value is seen ...
- only a count of non-blank fields is used for the division

Focusing on just the `HPA` column, a few modifications to OP's current `awk` code:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR>1  { key=$5
        arrkey[key]++
        HPAdiv[key]+= ($2=="" ? 0 : 1)
           HPA[key]+= $2+0
      }
END   { for (a in arrkey)
            print a, arrkey[a], (HPAdiv[a]==0 ? HPA[a] : HPA[a]/HPAdiv[a])
      }
' infile
```

**NOTES:**

- the `HPAdiv[a]==0 ? HPA[a] : HPA[a]/HPAdiv[a]` is added to insure we don't generate a 'divide by zero' error in the case where `HPAdiv[a]==0`; if 100% certain a 'divide by zero' error can never occur then this could be replaced with `HPA[a]/HPAdiv[a]`
- `GNU awk` has support for multidimensional arrays which may provide for a more modular approach for expanding the code to support the other columns (as opposed to creating a new pair of arrays for each additional column, eg, `TGKdiv[] / TGK[]` and `DIUdiv[] / DIU[]`)

This generates:

```
49_08_1975;5;945.65
49_08_1976;2;927.05
```

**NOTE:** the order of the output won't necessarily be guaranteed without some method of sorting (eg, piping the output to `sort`)

Comment: Magic. Extended it into 14 pairs to run on the big file and it works. Thanks so much! But what does this on the field counter do? ($2=="" ? 0 : 1)   And I also don't get what setting the counter to zero does, assuming that is what this means: HPAdiv[a]==0, nor what the question mark ? or the colon : do. Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: @anlom it's called a [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html) or a [ternary operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_ternary_operators.htm); regardless of the name it's basically an inline `if/then/else` construct ... `if $2==""` (2nd field is a blank) `then (return) 0` `else (return) 1`, so in this case the `+=` says to add a `0` or a `1` to our counter (`HPAdev[a]`) based on whether or not the 2nd field is a blank or non-blank, respectively

Answer (score 0):

side note : instead of having to check for denominator being non-zero, one could also use this trick -

**raise the denominator to its double-logically-negated power**

it works because a double-logical-negation yields a `boolean`

- `0/false` - for input value of `0`, or
- `1/true`  - for everything else

so every non-zero input gets back its own value while `0^0` returns a `1`

> ```
> function __(_) {
>         
>     return _^!!+_ 
> }
> ```

```
-5 -5
-4 -4
-3 -3
-2 -2
-1 -1
 0  1  <------
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
```

---

```
    # gawk profile, created Thu Apr 13 06:45:47 2023

    # Rule(s)

    11  ($++NF = __($!_))^_

    # Functions, listed alphabetically

    11  function __(_)
        {
    11      return _^!!+_
        }
```

another similar approach without using the power operator would instead require an addition:

> ```
> function __(_) {
>
>     return _+!+_
> }
> ```